# How to use angular bundles in index.ftl (freemarker template)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, webpack, freemarker, html-webpack-plugin

I am working on multi-module Gradle project having below structure

```sh
    parent-app
     - backend
        - src/main
            - java
            - resources
            - webapp
        - build.gradle
     - angular-ui
        - src
            - app
            - envirnoments
            - index.html
            - index.ftl
            - main.ts
        - angular.json
        - package.json
        - webpack.config.js
        - build.gradle
     - build.gradle
     - settings.gradle
```

I am using `index.ftl` (freemarker templates) as my view which uses some macros from in-house library (gradle dependencies) to get headers. But for everything else, I have to use angular components/pages.

I was trying with `webpack` to dynamically add angular bundles (main.js, polyfill.js etc) in `index.ftl` file.

The configuration throws `minify error` at angular build (`ng build --prod`) but I see js files are added in index.ftl as scripts.

Can anyone please help understand the issue and how to resolve it so that my angular bundle are fully loaded in index.ftl file without any errors.

Below is the error

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
<pre>
  Error: html-webpack-plugin could not minify the generated output.
  In production mode the html minifcation is enabled by default.
  If you are not generating a valid html output please disable it manually.
  You can do so by adding the following setting to your HtmlWebpackPlugin config:
  |
  |    minify: false
  |
  See https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options for details.
  For parser dedicated bugs please create an issue here:
  https://danielruf.github.io/html-minifier-terser/
  Parse Error: <#macro main> 
      <app-root></app-root> 
  <#macro> 
  <#maro pagebody> 
  <#macro><script src="angular-ui/runtime.689a94f98876eea3f04c.js"></script><script src="angular-ui/polyfills.94daefd414b8355106ab.js"></script><script src="angular-ui/main.95a9937db670e12d53ac.js"></script>
  
  - htmlparser.js:244 new HTMLParser
    [angular-webpack]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlparser.js:244:13
  
  - htmlminifier.js:993 minify
    [angular-webpack]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:993:3
  
  - htmlminifier.js:1354 Object.exports.minify
    [angular-webpack]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:1354:16
  
  - index.js:1019 HtmlWebpackPlugin.minifyHtml
    [angular-webpack]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:1019:46
  
  - index.js:435 HtmlWebpackPlugin.postProcessHtml
    [angular-webpack]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:435:40
  
  - index.js:260 
    [angular-webpack]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:260:25
  
  - task_queues:96 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5
  
</pre>
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    "publicPath": "angular-ui/"
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        "template": "./src/index.ftl",
        "filename": "../backend/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/index.ftl",
        "inject": false,
        "hash": true,
        "xhtml": true,
    }),
    {
      apply: (compile) => {
        compile.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
          fs.unlink(path.join(process.cwd(), "../backend/src/main/webapp/angular-ui/index.html"), (error) => {
            if (error) throw error;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

index.ftl

```html
<#macro main>
    <app-root></app-root>
<#macro>
<#maro pagebody>
<% for (key in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[key].entry) { %>
        <script src="<@spring.url '/<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[key].entry %>'/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
<#macro>
<@header>
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularUI</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "angular-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.17",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-ui": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "../backend/src/main/webapp/angular-ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-ui:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-ui:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular-ui:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular-ui:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular-ui"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` doesn't know how to correctly parse `.ftl` files. By default the plugin will use an `ejs-loader`. See https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/main/docs/template-option.md

Do you need to minify the index.ftl file? I'd argue that you don't. It's not necessary especially when you can just compress it before sending it from the server.  You should be able to pass the config property `minify` with the value of `false` into the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to prevent the minification error.

i.e.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  "template": "./src/index.ftl",
  "filename": "../backend/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/index.ftl",
  "inject": false,
  "hash": true,
  "xhtml": true,
  "minify": false // <-- property to add
}),
```

Adding the `minify: false` entry to the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` options should fix your immediate error.

**However**, I also noticed the `index.ftl` has a syntax error where you are trying to set the `src` attribute. There is an extra `'/>` before closing the `src` attribute. Specifically, you'll need to modify this line:

```
<script src="<@spring.url '/<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[key].entry %>'/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to be:

```
<script src="<@spring.url '/<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[key].entry %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Additionally, when testing locally, in order for my js files to be written to the file, I needed to change your line `htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks` to `htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js` because I'm not doing any chunking. You may need to do the same.